# R: Remove visual clutter from tracemem when used in function

Tags: r, function, trace, clutter

Tracemem is doing what I need it to, but it is also producing distracting visual clutter. Here is a simple example.

```
a<-1
b<-2

dummyfunction<-function(x,y){return(sum(x,y))}
dummyfunction(a,b)
[1] 3
```

Now, I want to do something more complex, first tracemem to see if the inputs are duplicated...

```
dummyfunction2<-function(x,y){if (tracemem(x)==tracemem(y)){return("Input vectors are identical")}
     if(sum(x %in% y)>=length(x) & sum(y %in% x)>=length(y)){print("Something something.")}
                              return(sum(x,y))}
```

This does what I want if the inputs are duplicated...

```
dummyfunction2(a,a)
[1] "Input vectors are identical"
```

When they're not duplicated, though the function still works, it spews a bunch of confusing information.

```
dummyfunction2(a,b)
tracemem[0x0000000009824470 -> 0x000000000a7ced80]: match %in% dummyfunction2 
tracemem[0x0000000009824500 -> 0x000000000a7cedb0]: match %in% dummyfunction2 
tracemem[0x0000000009824500 -> 0x000000000a7cef90]: match %in% dummyfunction2 
tracemem[0x0000000009824470 -> 0x000000000a7cc1a8]: match %in% dummyfunction2   
[1] 3
```

I'm hoping to convince non-R users to try using a function with this issue, and output like this will certainly scare them off.

What is the most elegent way to remove this visual clutter without supressing potentially informative warnings. etc that may crop up in other portions of the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/tracemem.html :

"This function marks an object so that a message is printed whenever the internal code copies the object."

You could stick untracemem into the function to get around it:

```
dummyfunction3<-function(x,y){
if (tracemem(x)==tracemem(y)){return("Input vectors are identical")}
untracemem(x)
untracemem(y)
if(sum(x %in% y)>=length(x) & sum(y %in% x)>=length(y)){print("Something something.")}
return(sum(x,y))}
```

output:

```
a <- 1
b <- 2
dummyfunction3(a,a)
# [1] "Input vectors are identical"
dummyfunction3(a,b)
# [1] 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `tracemem()`. Instead you could try `pryr::address()` which
just returns the memory address of the input.

```
devtools::install_github("hadley/pryr")

library(pryr)

x <- 1:10
y <- x

address(x)
## [1] "0x100a568c8"
address(y)
## [1] "0x100a568c8"
```